# Send-MailMessage full of "System.Object[]"after the first email

Tags: powershell

I have written a piece of powershell code to send emails to different users based on an extraction from a table (and some conditions).

```
#extraction skipped

foreach($row in $result) {

    Clear-Variable template* -Scope Global
    
    $template = (Get-Content "C:\template.html")

    #user definition skipped

        $message = "Hello..."      

        $html = $template |
            ForEach-Object { if($_.Trim() -eq "<p>$[CONTENT]</p>") {
              -join(($_).ToString().Replace("$[CONTENT]", $message),$html)
              } else { -join($_, $html) }
            }

        Send-MailMessage -From $fromAddr -To $mail -Bcc $maintainer -Subject $sub -Body ($html | Out-String) -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Encoding UTF8
}
```

If you need anything else feel free to ask, I felt like this was the relevant part of the code but I'm not 100% sure.

**The Problem:** Basically if i get only one user the email text looks fine. If there is more than one `$row` the second email is full of `System.Object[]`.

[image: Example of buggy resulting email]

I'm not sure what I've been doing wrong. My guess would be `ForEach-Object`, but why work for the first and not the following?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's with the complicated template substitution/concatenation logic? Why not just `$body = -join @((Get-Content .\template.html) -replace '\$\[CONTENT\]', $message)`

Comment: Two reasons: I'm bad at powershell, and it was born of many changes and iterations and never corrected. I guess it does not make sense. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code on the second iteration is that it's basically doing this:

```bsh
$html = $template | ... -join($_, $html) ...
```

where `$html` still contains the value from the first iteration, so you're joining the new `$message` with the entirety of the first email text and getting into a bit of a pickle.

You can avoid this if you add:

```bsh
$html = $null
$html = $template | ... -join($_, $html)
```

so each iteration gets a clean start.

Having said that, you can just do as @Mathias R. Jessen suggested and replace your entire templating logic with this:

```bsh
$body = -join @((Get-Content .\template.html) -replace '\$\[CONTENT\]', $message)
```

or more succinctly, this:

```bsh
$body = (Get-Content .\template.html -Raw).Replace("`$[CONTENT]", $message)
```